# display user roles in comment form

Tags: user-roles, comment-form

how can i show user's role in comment form near their name?!!
for example when admin reply a comment i want to show "admin" word near admin name
or when a user buy a product from my site and send a comment i want to show "buyer" role in near name
[image]

Comment: It seems you haven't try to search this by yourself! Anyway read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037576/in-wordpress-how-to-display-user-role-in-comments

Comment: i did but it doesnt work yet
please tell me what do i exactlly to do?!

Comment: What exactly have you already done?  Without seeing what you've attempted for yourself it is hard to offer help.  You might find [ask] useful.

Comment: i dont anything because i dont know.just know i need add something to comments.php file to display user role

Answer (score 1):

This will print `User Role`

```
global $current_user;
$user_role = $current_user->roles[0];
echo $user_role;
```

Use above code, where ever you want to display user role.

Comment: i want display in comment form and the problem is i cant access to comment list because in comment form for display comments used this function 
<?php
wp_list_comments( array(
'reply_text'        => '',
'avatar_size'       => 80,
) ); ?>

Comment: It would be better if you show your code so someone can help you! Its hard to offer help without seeing any code.

Comment: i use default comments.php file for my theme